# Are Managed Libraries inherited when a script is installed from the Google Apps Script Gallery?

Tags: google-apps-script

The documentation gives an indication of w[hat is copied when an Apps Script is installed from the Gallery](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/publishing_gallery#whats_published), but it is unclear if Managed Libraries used in a gallery script are also copied.

Are Managed Libraries inherited when a script is installed from the Google Apps Script Gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the library configuration should be copied along with a script when it's installed.

Comment: In the case of the script gallery, it's important that the library must be shared publicly, so that all users can access it.